# Case insensitive LIKE condition in LINQ (with Regular Expression)

Tags: c#, linq

I have following code that works if the search text and the items in the list are of same case (lower case / upper case). If there is a mixed casing it is not working,. How can we make it case insensitive search.

```
var text = "c";
var myStrings = new List<string>() { "Aa", "ACB", "cc" };
var regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(text);
var results = myStrings
        .Where<string>(item => regEx.IsMatch(item))
        .ToList<string>();
```

EDIT :

I need to pass that string with Case Insensitive to the method how can i do that ...

```
  public ActionResult GetItems(string text)
  {
        ContextObject contextObject = new ContextObject();          
        TransactionHistory transactionhistory = new TransactionHistory();
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var items = transactionhistory.GetItems(contextObject, text);

        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                     
  }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5845fdz.aspx <-- its in the docs

Comment: This code can be written more concisely: 1) Add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions` to the top of the file, and define the type using `Regex`. 2) Use a collection initializer to load the list. 3) Use `var` for the list and the regular expression. 4) The only place you need to pass a type parameter is when creating a `new List<string>()`; it is unnecessary anywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to declare your regex like this

```
Regex regEx = new Regex(text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: You can also add `(?i)` at the beginning of the value of `text`. But passing the option as an argument is usually the better solution.

Comment: @TGH   I need to pass that case insensitive string as a parameter  to that method how can i pass in this case would you pls suggest any idea..

Comment: @richardtallent  I need to pass that case insensitive string as a parameter to that method how can i pass in this case would you pls suggest any idea..

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the overload which takes [RegexOptions.IgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5845fdz.aspx)

Example

```
 RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled;
 System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(text, options);
```

EDIT:

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled;            
var text = "c";
var myStrings = new List<string>() { "Aa", "ACB", "cc" };
var regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(text, options);
var results = myStrings
             .Where<string>(item => regEx.IsMatch(item))
             .ToList<string>();

//you will have 2 items in results
foreach(string s in results)
{
    GetItems(s);
}
```

Comment: I need to pass that case insensitive string as a parameter to that method(`transactionhistory.GetItems`) how can i pass in this case would you pls suggest any idea..

Comment: How can i pass that caseInsensitive string to that method

Comment: your question isn't clear. what do you mean by passing case-insensitive string as a parameter?

Comment: I need to pass `text` value as a case insensitive to that method mentioned above how can i pass ....

Comment: what do you mean by passing case in-sensitive string. There isn't any such thing as in-sensitive string. Comparison can be case sensitive or in-sensitive.

Comment: i am not able to get the string(i.e text) from this regex  how  can i get `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(text, options);` mentioned in my edit method ...

Answer (score 0):

Based in your code, why using a regex? I would use a regex only with complex text patterns. In this case is way easier to use string.IndexOf() like in

```
var text = "c";
var myStrings = new List<string>() { "Aa", "ACB", "cc" };
var results = myStrings
    .Where(item => item.IndexOf(text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    .ToList();
```

I have al removed the explicit use of string in where and toList as it is applied by default.